# Spring Data JPA find by nested object id (nested twice)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible?

I'd like to get all AAA objects with a specific CCC.incidentAssessmentResultId id using JPARepository. Is it possible?

```
   @Entity
    @Table(schema = "aaa", name = "table")
    public class AAA {

        @Column(name = "kryterium")
        private String criterion;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_kryterium_naruszen")
        private List<BBB> violationFactors;

    }

    public class BBB {

        @Column(name = "czynnik")
        private String factor;

        @Column(name = "stopien")
        private float degree;

        @JsonManagedReference
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "violationFactor")
        private CCC incidentAssessmentFactor;
}

public class CCC {

    @Column(name="komentarz")
    private String comment;

    @Column(name="ocena_naruszenia_wynik_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Long incidentAssessmentResultId; //-> I'd like to find AAA objects with a specific incidentAssessmentResultId ID

    @Column(name="czynnik_wybrany")
    private Boolean factorIsSelected;

    @Column(name = "wartosc_wybrana")
    private float value;


    @Repository
    public interface ViolationCriterionRepository extends JpaRepository<AAA, Long> {

    //  @Query("select vc from AAA vc left join vc.violationFactors vf left join vf.incidentAssessmentFactor iaf where iaf.incidentAssessmentResultId = ?1")
        List<AAA> findByViolationFactors_IncidentAssessmentFactor_IncidentAssessmentResultId(Long incidentId);
    }
```

Now, when I call ViolationCriterionRepository .findAll() I get all data but I want to get all data but with certain CCC objects. I've tried with the method below in my Repository but I get 0 results.

**UPDATE**

My repo:

```
@Repository
public interface ViolationCriterionRepository extends JpaRepository<ViolationCriterion, Long> {

    @Query("select vc from AAA vc join vc.violationFactors vf join vf.incidentAssessmentFactor iaf where iaf.incidentAssessmentResultId = ?1")
    List<AAA> findByIncidentAssessmentResultId(Long incidentId);
}
```

Comment: Uncomment your query, and choose a readable name for your method. That should be sufficient (assuming ViolationCriterion and AAA are the same thing). I would use inner joins rather than left joins though.

Comment: Yes, I changed my Repo to AAA... give me a moment

Comment: Unfortunately error: Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'cv' {originalText=cv}

Comment: You're using `select cv`, and then `from ViolationCriterion vc`. Be consistent. It's either vc, or cv.

Comment: Yes, you're right - typo... Now without errors but still 0 results

Comment: That simply means that no row exists in your database that matches your criteria.

Comment: Yes, I made some mistake - but @JB Nizet - thank you very much for your help

Comment: But I have one more question... I have 4 rows in AAA table... When I call violationCriterionRepository.findAll() I get 4 AAA objects with different lists of List<BBB> violationFactors... Is there a possibility to return the same structure? I have 4 elements in table AAA and I'd like to get List of 4 elements and each with the list of List<BBB> violationFactors;

Comment: I found the solution! @Query("select vc from ViolationCriterion vc join vc.violationFactors vf join vf.incidentAssessmentFactor iaf join iaf.incidentAssessment ia where ia.incidentAssessmentId = ?1 group by vc ")

Comment: General remark: please clean your question to the essence of what you want to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the AAAJpaRepository:

```
List<AAA> aaaList = findByViolationFactorsIncidentAssessmentFactorIncidentAssessmentResultId( long incidentAssessmentResultId);
```

Comment: Works too! But how to add groupBy clause in this case? With query the solution is @Query("select vc from AAA vc join vc.violationFactors vf join vf.incidentAssessmentFactor iaf join iaf.incidentAssessment ia where ia.incidentAssessmentId = ?1 group by vc ")

Comment: You can at grouping at the end of the query string. See the spring jpa reference for examples

Comment: Yeah me neither .. sorry for that. I think I confused it with order by. However, you can do the grouping in memory. I would anyways recommend changing the return value to a stream. Than (or after streaming the list) you can use java streams `groupingBy`. Note that you have to close the stream manually or better use it inside a try with block.

Answer (score 2):

And the answer is (@JB Nizet - many thanks!):

```
@Repository
public interface ViolationCriterionRepository extends JpaRepository<ViolationCriterion, Long> {

    @Query("select vc from AAA vc join vc.violationFactors vf join vf.incidentAssessmentFactor iaf join iaf.incidentAssessment ia where ia.incidentAssessmentId = ?1 group by vc ")
    List<ViolationCriterion> findIncidentAssessmentByIncidentAssessmentId(Long incidentId);
}
```