# Spring boot JPA filter data based on relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities in my Project. Entity A (eA) has an One-to-Many relationship with Entity B (eB) and eB has an One-to-Many relationship with Entity C (eC). I have fetch = eager in all of them.

I want to get eA with eB and eC nested but i want to get specific entries from eC. I have created a simple query like this

```
SELECT eA.* from eA
INNER JOIN eB on eA.eB_id = eB.id
INNER JOIN eC on eB.eC_id = eC.id
WHERE eC.id IN (1,2,3)
```

It actually seems to work when I run this directly in the database but when I create function in my repository with this query it returns all data from eB and eC and the right ones based on the WHERE clause.

I have tried switching fetch to lazy but with no luck.

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a JPA query? I am not sure how supported it is to filter the relationship beforehand. Something I found [is this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60863789/select-only-a-subset-of-an-entities-collection)

Comment: It looks relevant but it that case the function would be findeAsByeBsByeCs (or something like that) which does not seem to be possible cause its the "third level" which I need to apply the clause to

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a [derived query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) in your repository interface, no SQL needed. Spring Data can derive queries based only on the name of a repository method and its parameter type(s). It's a powerful feature, useful to avoid the need to write SQL or JPQL queries manually. [Here is another useful explanation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries) with some examples.

For your case, the repository method name to filter nested objects would be somewhat complex, but doable. The exact repository method name depends on the field names in your entity classes, which you didn't show us. So assuming classes like this (annotations omitted):

```java
public class A {
    private long id;
    private Collection<B> entityBs;
}

public class B {
    private long id;
    private Collection<C> entityCs;
}

public class C {
    private long id;
}
```

The repository method would look like this:

```java
public interface EntityARepository extends JPARepository<A, long> {
    Collection<A> findByEntityBsEntityCsIdIn(long[] ids);
}
```

The return type of the repo method can be other types, [as documented here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-return-types), depending on how you want the results returned.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I used JPA Buddy and it was a big help but unfortunately the results are the same. I passed the ids but i get every EntityB and inside each one I get every EntityC

Comment: I know this works, I've done it before (not nested 3 levels deep, but 2). [Here is another SO Q&A that's basically the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56418909/639520)

Comment: Yeah I know it works too. I have used it before. It seems to work now. I get results but I get all the rows from Entity C. They do not get filtered out by the ids I am passing as an argument.